# Best way to store data for fast retrival and low DB cycles?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing Online Examination web application where candidates can attempt for various papers online.

Exam module have lots of settings related to exam like NegativeMarksPerQuestion,ShowResult,UpdateElapsedTime etc.

when candidate submits answer I have to check answer is correct if not the I am fetching NegativeMarksPerQuestion setting from DB and then `insert` candidate's answer to DB. likewise for each answer for each candidate.

I don't want to fetch such settings each time from DB (or is it okay to do so; as lots of candidate can give exam concurrently?). I am thinking to store such settings somewhere so that it can retrieved faster without going DB each time.

Comment: Storing such data in `session\LRU cache` is okay?

Comment: Have you ever came across NOSQL . Thats the fastest and the best way of storing and retreving data. Even google use NOSQL in their DATABASE .

Comment: @Amogh i don't think it will be good idea to store data in session as number of concurrent users are more.`NOSQL` can be an option.

Comment: @Khay I no idea about NOSQL is there any document/link that u have?

Comment: @Amogh u can refer this link for basics http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/11/what-is-nosql.html

Comment: @Khay @Khay As this web application is already developed and deployed over RDBMS (Mysql).And what I understood is for NoSQL I have to use DB like `mongodb` right?

Comment: But there are ways to shift your RDBMS  to nosql , no the question is is your application worth taking so much pain or not

Comment: @Khay As our product can be fully online where candidate can give exam over the net (WWW) or Partial online mode where an exam center locally deploy the website on tomcat or glassfish and then they can sync. data using an utility...and currently 5000+ centers are on quasi mode..so it is not possible to shift to NoSql...any other option.?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for NOSQL databases in particular then http://www.mongodb.org/ should be ideal choice, as it is documented well and good community support.

With any SQL db, it would be good to use caching support like http://www.hazelcast.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure . And what I would strongly suggest is to learn NoSQL nicely because it has very long running advantages. You can use any of these links for beginners tutorials:

[Github](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Tutorial%3a-Introduction-to-the-NoSQL-world)[No-SQL W3schools](http://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/nosql.php)

Comment: Did you find something ???

Comment: As this web application is already developed and deployed over RDBMS (Mysql).And what I understood is for NoSQL I have to use DB like `mongodb` right?

Comment: yea thats one of the ways @Amogh

Comment: But there are ways to shift your RDBMS to nosql , no the question is is your application worth taking so much pain or not @Amogh

Comment: Okay let me suggest this to org.